# $.get request not working locally on ios devices

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

Whilst the issues on ajax requests and iOS have been somewhat well documented, I can't seem to find anything that fixes my simple $.get issue. Please note this is a rails app, working on a local machine.

Below is some coffeescript which fetches a users notifications and displays them in a div. This works nicely on everything locally, including kindle when visiting the local IP address (real IP omitted for code below), but not on any iOS device.

I have tried adding the absolute path as the URL instead of `/activites/notifications`. I have also written it as an AJAX and $.get request but neither work on iOS.

How can I get the GET request below to work locally on iOS devices?

GET Request

```
jQuery ->
      arr = []
      $("#notifications").click ->
        arr.push(1)
        if arr.length <= 1
          $.get("http://68.40.3.2:3000/activities/notifications", (data) ->
             $("#notifications-area").html data )
```

AJAX Request

```
jQuery ->
  arr = []
  $("#notifications").click ->
    arr.push(1)
    if arr.length <= 1
     $.ajax({
       url: "http://68.40.3.2:3000/activities/notifications",
       cache: false,
       timeout: 100000,
       type: "GET",
       error: -> alert("didnt work")
       success: (data) ->
            $("#notifications-area").html data
    })
```

If anyone needs more code just shout.

Comment: This was used to omit my real IP address. A placeholder

Comment: So you're using a real IP in your real code but your iOS device refuses to do it? Have you tried trying to access that URL directly from Mobile Safari's URL bar? I've never had any problems accessing things by IP on my local network using my iPad.

Comment: Yep i can access the url through the mobile safari URL bar no problems, which renders the notifications as expected, its only when I try and request them via this $.get request that nothing works. I couldn't see any javascript warnings over the safari and xcode dev tools either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that bootstrap was the culprit. I am using the conventional bootstrap navbar and dropdown elements. Specifically the `.dropdown` class and `data-toggle` elements in the anchor link somehow caused the records to not load/not be shown. If anyone knows why this happens or an update from bootstrap it would be great to hear it. For now here is how I resolved the issue.

Navbar structure. Removed data-toggle and dropdown class from anchor tag.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a id="notifications" href="#" class="<%= number_of_activities(current_user) > 0 ? 'new-notifications' : '' %>" title="Notifications">
      <div class="notifications-count large" id="">
        <%= number_of_activities(current_user) %>
      </div>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu span6" id="notifications-area">
  </ul>
</li>
```

notifications.js.coffee remains much the same expect toggling notifications area before the records load, and the stopPropagation calls so that the div is closed when you click outside the notifications area

```
 jQuery ->
   arr = []
    $("#notifications").click (e) ->
      arr.push(1)
      e.stopPropagation()
      $('#notifications-area').toggle()
      if arr.length <= 1
        $.get("/activities/notifications", (data) ->
          $("#notifications-area").html data )

 $('#notifications-area').click (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()

 $(document).click ->
    $("#notifications-area").hide()
```